# PANDAS inputing a specific ID based on a wildcard

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe where a single experiment can have multiple rows because each experiment has different tags. I created a new column called `sign_up_field`. Basically, I want to wildcard 'Multiple input field' to impute all experiments that contain this tag to be a sign-up field. How can I do this when I have multiple rows for a single experiment and I want to input each experiment that contains this tag?

this is my DF

```
experiment company    tag                    sign_up_field
1          facebook   Multiple input field   NaN
1          facebook   One button             NaN
1          facebook   Get Started            NaN
```

and my expected output is

```
experiment company    tag                    sign_up_field
1          facebook   Multiple input field   1
1          facebook   One button             1
1          facebook   Get Started            1
```

I've tried

`df['sign_up_field'].loc[df['tag'].str.contains('Multiple input field', flags=re.IGNORECASE)] = 1`

But this will only input the first row when I want to impute all 3 since they're the same experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, what you want is the following:

1. Get all the experiments for which there is at least a row with 'Multiple input  field' in the tag columns
2. Set the column 'sign_up_field' to be 1 for all those.

If that is the case, you can achieve it with the following code:

```py
experiments = df.loc[df['tag'].str.contains('Multiple input field', flags=re.IGNORECASE), 'experiment']

df.loc[df['experiment'].isin(experiments), 'sign_up_field'] = 1
```

Considering the string is an exact match and not a regular expression, you can be more concise:

```py
experiments = df.loc[df['tag'] == 'Multiple input field', 'experiment']
df.loc[df['experiment'].isin(experiments), 'sign_up_field'] = 1
```

If `experiment` is an index and not a column, you will need to change this line:

```py
experiments = df.loc[df['tag'] == 'Multiple input field', 'experiment']
```

to this one:

```py
experiments = df.loc[df['tag'] == 'Multiple input field'].index
```

Comment: This is awesome. What if there are multiple experiments like this where I need to wildcard? Is there a better method than creating an experiments variable each time for different wild cards?

Comment: This work for any number of experiments that have at least one row with 'Multiple input field'. If you have more than that string, you can do `df['tag'].isin([ 'Multiple input field', 'Other string', 'A third string'])` instead of `df['tag'] == 'Multiple input field'`. You'd gather all experiment with at least one of those strings. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, but I was trying to do it in the first method with a wildcard statement, can i do str.contains for multiple tags?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't look nice. You need to use a regex for an "OR" between your tags, which is the pipe ("|"). For example, this matches the 3 rows: `pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'C']).str.contains("A|B|C")`.

Comment: Please remember to accept and upvote the answer if it solved your question! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try with two steps `transform`

```
df['sign_up_field'] = df['tag'].str.contains('Multiple input field', flags=re.IGNORECASE)]

df['sign_up_field'] = df.groupby('experiment')['sign_up_field'].transform('any')
```